# Can we add Modules tag after Build tag in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a maven project in which I have multiple components with individual pom.xml. I wanted to compile class from one component, then copy some of the class files to other component using maven-ant-run plugin and then execute that module.

So If I add the module tag after the build tag, will it work?
Does maven maintain order?

Answer (score 0):

No, the parent POM is always build first and then all the modules.

The order in which the modules are build is mainly determined by their dependencies on each other.